# SQL join with concat and substring

Tags: sql, join, substring, concatenation

So I'm attempting to do a join that requires both CONCAT and SUBSTRING.

Table one has a column with a date and location e.g. '02:00 IND'

Table two has a column with date/time e.g. '2020-10-10 02:00:00.000000' and another column with location e.g. 'IND'.

This is the statement that I'm trying but it isn't working:

```
       SELECT * 
       FROM FIRST_TABLE
       INNER JOIN SECOND_TABLE on FIRST_TABLE.TIME_LOCATION = 
       CONCAT(SUBSTRING(SECOND_TABLE.TIME,12,5) , SECOND_TABLE.LOCATION);
```

I am receiving the below error:

> [SQL0171] Argument 1 of function
> SUBSTRING not valid. Cause . . . . . : The data type, length, or value
> of argument 1 of function SUBSTRING specified is not valid. Recovery .
> . . : Refer to the DB2 for IBM i SQL Reference topic collection in the
> Database category in the IBM i Information Center for more information
> on scalar functions. Correct the arguments specified for the function.
> Try the request again

Comment: What’s the datatypes of the 3 fields?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no space when you concat the substrings.

It will look like this:

02:00IND

I am guessing it is just returning a blank result as you have not mention it was returning an error :)

Comment: Oops, yes I was using ' ' I just forgot to put it in there. I am receiving an error message [SQL0171] Argument 1 of function SUBSTRING not valid. Cause . . . . . :   The data type, length, or value of argument 1 of function SUBSTRING specified is not valid. Recovery  . . . :   Refer to the DB2 for IBM i SQL Reference topic collection in the Database category in the IBM i Information Center for more information on scalar functions. Correct the arguments specified for the function. Try the request again.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work if anyone ever has a similar issue. I am a beginner in SQL so I don't know if this will be helpful or not, I'm sure there is a better way of doing it.

Anyway, my issue was that the data types were incompatible. I cast the timestamp as time which left me with a 'HH.MM.SS' format. After that I had to cast it into a NVARCHAR to make a substring that excluded the seconds. And THEN I had to replace the '.' with a ':' to make the values match. It was a lot of work but I figured it out!

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM FIRST_TABLE
   INNER JOIN SECOND_TABLE on FIRST_TABLE.TIME_LOCATION = 
   CONCAT(CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CAST(TIME(SECOND_TABLE.TIME)AS NVARCHAR(8)), 1, 5), 
   '.', ':'), ' '), DSP134.LSDTID);
```